# How to setup less4j

Tags: less

I looking for a less to css compiler in java, and found, among others, [less4j](https://github.com/SomMeri/less4j). I want to give it a try, but the problem is
I haven´t been able to find how to use it. I search for related topics but only found advanced questions; in the project documentation I coudn´t find anything either. What I want to do is use it inside a project where I am going to write my less files and compile them to css. There is a pom.xml file; the issue is I don´t know maven. So, my question is wheter I can use it in a diffrent way (I don´t want a jar, what I want are classes inside a eclipse project) or I have to made the jar file using maven. I know this is something reallly trivial but I don´t know how to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As documented on less4j project [home page](https://github.com/SomMeri/less4j), the easiest way to integrate less4j into java project is using [wro4j](http://alexo.github.io/wro4j/) library. You can use it as a [maven plugin](https://code.google.com/p/wro4j/wiki/MavenPlugin) or for on the fly compilation using a filter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have already been able to use it inside a maven project, including some dependencies in pom.xml. It was easier to understand a little bit about maven than try to figure it out how to use it in an alternative way.